# What does the phrase "as thick AROUND as" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

> Each line, as thick around as a big pencil, was looped onto a green-sapped stick...

*From "The old man and the sea" by Ernest Hemingway*

I have two questions:

1. Does it describe the thickness of the line?
2. What does **around** mean here? I mean what's wrong with "as thick as"?

Comment: Q1 Yes, Q2 nothing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to recognize the precise meaning of "line." The use of "pencil" in the sentence might make you think of a line drawn on a piece of paper. But the lines are *looped onto sticks*, so the meaning is actually:

> Etymology 1, definition 2. A rope, cord, string, or thread, of any thickness. ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line#Etymology_1))

So "as thick **around**" is a way of describing the **circumference** of a line (rope, cord, etc). In the sciences things like this are usually described in terms of their **diameter** instead, but describing them in terms of circumference is not incorrect. Hemingway is saying that the circumference of each rope is the same as the circumference of a pencil.